# Wordpress rewrite url /?

Tags: wordpress, redirect, url-rewriting

I am having trouble to redirect the url from location/?landingpagetype=wedding to redirect to location/wedding with the same content as above?

i have tried various plugins but could not hit the spot.

Any suggestions would be higly appreciated ?

Comment: did you flush rewrite rules WordPress? please refer this answer https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/123401/where-when-how-to-properly-flush-rewrite-rules-within-the-scope-of-a-plugin

Comment: You can start with what @Bhautik mentioned. Also how exactly have you tried to redirect the URL? And how does your webserver rewrite rules in configuration file look like?

Comment: I am basically a layman here, what do you suggest how should i proceed ?